# override magento block

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

hello im trying to voerrride a block with my own module:

the Block:age_Downloadable_Block_Customer_Products_List
 but it is not working this the  block code:

```
  class module_name_Block_Customer_Products_List extends    Mage_Downloadable_Block_Customer_Products_List
{

    /**
     * Class constructor
```

end the config file for module is:

```
 <global>
        <blocks>
            <module_name> <!-- class group -->
                <class>module_name</class> <!-- path to class -->
            </module_name>            
        </blocks>
        <blocks>
            <downloadable>
            <customer>
                 <rewrite>
                     <products_list>module_name_Block_Customer_Products_List</products_list>
                 </rewrite>
            </customer>
            </downloadable>
     </blocks>
```

i have already flushed cache an reactive module in back end but it is not working.

Could you give me  a hand?

Comment: I think some code is missing

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is a bit off, this should work for you:

```
<blocks>
   <downloadable>
      <rewrite>
         <customer_products_list>Module_Name_Block_Customer_Products_List</customer_products_list>
      </rewrite>
   </downloadable>
</blocks>
```

The module name you are overriding should be the first node inside of the  node.  Followed by rewrite, and finally the node inside of rewrite should be the path from "Block_" to the end of the class.

A bit more:  You can use the same structure to override a helper or a model too.